# How to change magento config programatically for different stores?

Tags: magento

I have a list of custom options in magento config and I need to change them programmatically when an user clicks on "Save Config". In generally it's not a big problem to get it done using observer but I need to have one option like "Pack of options" and if user choose one of package appropriate options must be changed programatically. It's not a big deal too:

```
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('path/to/config/', 1, 'default', 0);
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('path/to/config2/', 1, 'default', 0);
```

But the problem is that I can't get it working for different stores, it's working for default scope only. Example:

```
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('path/to/config2/', 1, 'german', 0);
```

isn't working.

How can I update options programatically for certain stores only? So the user could check witch store he wants to apply options too?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$storeCode = 'german';
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeCode);
$path = 'path/to/config';
$config = Mage::getModel('core/config_data');
$config->setValue('Your value here');
$config->setPath($path);
$config->setScope('stores');
$config->setScopeId($store->getId());
$config->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the definition of the function :

```
 public function saveConfig($path, $value, $scope = 'default', $scopeId = 0)
```

The scope can actually take only 3 values : 'default', 'stores' or 'websites'.
Let's suppose your german store has 3 as Id, here is the code that would work :

```
$config = Mage::getModel('core/config');
$config->saveConfig('path/to/config/', 'value_to_set', 'stores', 3);
```

For a website-scoped config :

```
$config->saveConfig('path/to/config/', 'value_to_set', 'websites', $websiteId);
```

Comment: I just want to point out that I tried to edit this post to add the two missing single quotations but this site doesn't let you do so unless you are changing more than six characters. What up with that? Anyway, just pretend that such an edit was made.

Comment: Oh Yes indeed, thank you for pointing that out, I just edited it !